# Using keyboard shortcuts to resize/position individual windows

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, resizing

I'm using Windows 8.1 and have recently bought a 4k monitor. I want to make full use of the desktop estate I have. That's why I have all my application windows set to 1/4th the available size. But having to use my mouse to carefully position each window every single time is getting annoying.

I know windows has `WIN+Arrow Left` and `WIN+Arrow Right`, but these shortcuts fill up the entire vertical space if you use them. I only want to snap them to corners without resizing or anything.

Having an application that can divide my screen in grids and resize and snap applications to those grids would be amazing. I know OS X has an application like that, but I was wondering whether Windows has one as well.

Comment: Coming in Windows 10 [Snap: A truly slick feature in Windows 10](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/snap-a-truly-slick-feature-in-windows-10/) - You can now snap windows to the four corners and the two windows in a split-screen formation. There are other cool new features as well.

Comment: That's very cool. I hope something like that is also available in previous Windows'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I only want to snap them to corners without resizing or anything

Take a look at [AquaSnap](http://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap)

> Drag & Drop your windows to the sides or corners of the screen and they are automatically resized to fit one half or one quarter of the screen. Just like the built-in Aero Snap function of Windows 7 but with more possibilities! This is especially useful on a 4K monitor or on multiple monitors.

...

> AquaSnap is compatible with all Windows versions, from Windows XP to Windows 8.1, with true 64-bit support,

...

> AquaSnap is free for a personal use, try it now!

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [AquaSnap](http://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap)
 in any way,

Comment: Thank you @davidpostill this is exactly what I'm looking for!